# Elastic beanstalk - change values in a file

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have an elastic beanstalk app (php with amazon linux)
We have a configuration file that we need to change some values in it when the instance is setup.

How can we do it automatically for each instance?
Should we put add something to ebextenstions that downloads the 'correct' configuration file with wget and overwrites that file?

Answer (score 0):

As you said you can use a config that downloads your config file and saves it to a specific location https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-files. However, I don't exactly know the behavior if you try to override a file that already exists.